# Spring Boot map OneToMany realionship request value to controller model

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, autowired

Ok, so I'm starting to learn Spring Boot and I'm struggling with model values mapping on the client.

It seems to work ok with standard fields, but when I have a field which represents a relationship between two tables, the system seems unable to automatically identify the selected value, although it seems pretty intuitive it should be capable of doing it.

So, I have two model classes reflecting banks and clients, where every client has an associated bank:

This is Client class

```
package databaseModel;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Clientes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_banco")
    private Banco banco;
    
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String direccion;
    private String documento;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Banco getBanco() {
        return banco;
    }
    
    public void setBanco(Banco banco) {
        this.banco = banco;
    }
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }
    
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
    
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    
    public String getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }
    
    public void setDocumento(String documento) {
        this.documento = documento;
    }
    
}
```

And this is Bank class

```
package databaseModel;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    
    @Entity
    public class Banco {
    
        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        
        private String cif;
        private String bic;
        private String direccion;
        private String nombre;
        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "banco")
        private List<Clientes> clientes;
        
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        public String getCif() {
            return cif;
        }
        
        public void setCif(String cif) {
            this.cif = cif;
        }
        
        public String getBic() {
            return bic;
        }
        
        public void setBic(String bic) {
            this.bic = bic;
        }
        
        public String getDireccion() {
            return direccion;
        }
        
        public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
            this.direccion = direccion;
        }
        
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
        
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }   
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to create a page where a new client can be added. For this, I have two controller methods, one for managing the form rendering and another one to retrieve form data converted into Client model and saving it to database.

These are my controller methods:

```
@Controller
public class Controladores {

    @Autowired
    private ClientesRepository clientes;
    
    @Autowired
    private BancoRepository bancos;
    
    @GetMapping("/nuevoCliente")
    public String nuevoCliente(Model model) {
        Clientes nuevoCliente = new Clientes();
        model.addAttribute("cliente", nuevoCliente);
        model.addAttribute("bancos", bancos.findAll());
        
        return "nuevoCliente";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/nuevoCliente")
    public String nuevoCliente(@ModelAttribute Clientes nuevoCliente, Model model) {
        
        clientes.save(nuevoCliente);
        
        model.addAttribute("clientes", clientes.findAll());
        
        return "gestionClientes";
    }
}
```

And, finally, I have a view where a form is rendered so users can send new client data to server:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Gestión bancaria</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<p>Alta de un nuevo usuario, por favor, introduce los datos del usuario y pulsa el botón guardar</p>

    <form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/nuevoCliente}" th:object="${cliente}">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <input type="text" th:field="*{apellidos}" placeholder="Apellidos" />
        <input type="text" th:field="*{documento}" placeholder="NIF" />
        <input type="text" th:field="*{direccion}" placeholder="Dirección" />
        <select th:field="*{banco}">
            <option th:each="banco: ${bancos}" th:value="${banco}" th:text=${banco.nombre} /> 
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I try to send the form, an exception rises:

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='clientes'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'clientes' on field 'banco': rejected value [databaseModel.Banco@5adaf23d]; codes [typeMismatch.clientes.banco,typeMismatch.banco,typeMismatch.databaseModel.Banco,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [clientes.banco,banco]; arguments []; default message [banco]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'databaseModel.Banco' for property 'banco'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'databaseModel.Banco@5adaf23d'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "databaseModel.Banco@5adaf23d"]

As far as I understand... the framework is unable to convert the value stored on the bank select to the bank class type. I wonder... if everything is correctly wired, shouldn't the engine be capable of correctly guessing which data has to load into the new client object banco attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: the `<option ... />` tag holds a string representation of the `Banco` object, i.e something like `databaseModel.Banco@212313221`. It cannot be bound to a `Banco` object.

The simplest solution would be to hold only the `banco.id` (`th:field` and `th:value` attributes):

```
<select th:field="*{banco.id}">
    <option th:each="banco: ${bancos}" th:value="${banco.id}" th:text=${banco.nombre} /> 
</select>
```

It would work, but you would get an incomplete `Banco` in the controller: only `id` would be set. You would need to perform a database lookap manually.

Another option would be to create a custom type converter. The `<select>` tag would send the `banco.id` as the value of the `client.banco`, and the converter would preform the DB look-up.

```
<select th:field="*{banco}">
    <option th:each="banco: ${bancos}" th:value="${banco.id}" th:text=${banco.nombre} /> 
</select>
```

```
@Component
public class BancoConverter implements Converter<String, Banco> {

    @Autowired
    private BancoRepository bancos;

    @Override
    public Banco convert(String id) {
        return bancos.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I solved it adding to Clientes.java a getter and a setter to manage id_banco property and using banco.id in the form. It seemed somewhat more elegant to me than using a converter. The fun fact is that I was totally convinced that Hibernate engine would be capable of doing exactly that out of the box, as I'm telling all info it needs just with annotations.